# Getting error: The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect

Tags: java, spring-mvc

On one of the action I want it to take a POST of content. I am sending the following values:

```
        permissionId = $('#permissionId').val();
        var emails   = $.trim($('#emails', win).val());
        var sms      = $.trim($('#sendSms', win).is(':checked'));
        var email    = $.trim($('#sendEmail', win).is(':checked'));
        var override = $.trim($('#cannotOverride', win).is(':checked'));            

window.location = '/aims/monitoringPermissions/' + permissionId + '/' + emails + '/' + sms + '/' + email+ '/' + override+ '/' + monitId;
```

However, when I send it I am getting the following error:

```
The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect.
```

My action looks like this

```
  @RequestMapping(value="/monitoringPermissions/{permissionId}/{emails}/{sms}/{email}/{override}/{monitId}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
  public ModelAndView submitPermissions(@PathVariable long roleId, @PathVariable String emails,
        @PathVariable boolean canSendSMS, @PathVariable boolean canSendEmail, @PathVariable boolean cannotOverride, @PathVariable long monitoringId,Model model, HttpSession session,
        Principal principal, @ModelAttribute("permission") MonitoringPermission monitoringPermission) throws Exception {
```

Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have incorrect @pathvariable variable names:

**Spring automatically matches a path variable to a parameter that has the exact same name**
should be something like:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/monitoringPermissions/{permissionId}/{emails}/{sms}/{email}/{override}/{monitId}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
  public ModelAndView submitPermissions(@PathVariable long permissionId, @PathVariable String emails,
        @PathVariable boolean sms, @PathVariable boolean email, @PathVariable boolean override, @PathVariable long monitId,Model model, HttpSession session,
        Principal principal, @ModelAttribute("permission") MonitoringPermission monitoringPermission) throws Exception {
```

or something like:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/monitoringPermissions/{permissionId}/{emails}/{sms}/{email}/{override}/{monitId}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
  public ModelAndView submitPermissions(@PathVariable("permissionId") long roleId, @PathVariable("emails") String emails,
        @PathVariable("sms") boolean canSendSMS, @PathVariable("email") boolean canSendEmail, @PathVariable("override") boolean cannotOverride, @PathVariable("monitId") long monitoringId,Model model, HttpSession session,
        Principal principal, @ModelAttribute("permission") MonitoringPermission monitoringPermission) throws Exception {
```